# How can i move these small images?

Tags: html, css, image

Firt off, I am new to coding. I have this site im building and i want to be able to move the two small photos side by side.

I have tried absolute and relative positioning as well as moving the image with margin-left and margin-right, but it still wont move they way i want it to.

I would like the images to move with the screen when i make the screen smaller or larger.

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row>.column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.column1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.column2 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.column2 img {
  position: relative;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.planerium.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/all-seasons-coloring-page-numbers-one.webp" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>



  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
        <img src="https://www.planerium.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/all-seasons-coloring-page-numbers-one.webp" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
        <img src="https://www.planerium.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/all-seasons-coloring-page-numbers-two.webp" style="width:100%">
      </div>


      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

      <div class="caption-container">
        <p id="caption"></p>
      </div>


      <div class="column1">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.planerium.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/all-seasons-coloring-page-numbers-one.webp" style="width:50%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Back">
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.planerium.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/all-seasons-coloring-page-numbers-two.webp" style="width:50%;" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Front">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

There is the code and here what it looks like (https://ibb.co/HPPY4J9)

Is there anyway to get both numbers side by side?

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? Dont use float. Either wrap them and use flexbox or use "inline"

Comment: Wrap your two columns `column1 and `column2` in a div and add `display: flex;` to that element. Then add what ever flex properties you want, like justify-content or align-items, etc..  Remove all that floating on those elements as well.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: @dalelandry Is there a way to add two of these? Like add the number 3 and when i click on it if shows 3 and 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can just wrap the divs of small images inside a parent div and use the "flex" property to make them side by side. Here I have modified your code, please check the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  margin-left:10px;
  width: 100%;
  
}

.column1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left:0px;
  width: 100%;
  
}

.column2 {
  
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
}
.column2 img{
  position: relative;
  
}




/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.column-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.column-wrapper div{
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
}
</style>
<body>



<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.planerium.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/all-seasons-coloring-page-numbers-one.webp" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>



<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
      <img src="https://www.planerium.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/all-seasons-coloring-page-numbers-one.webp" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
      <img src="https://www.planerium.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/all-seasons-coloring-page-numbers-two.webp" style="width:100%">
    </div>


    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column-wrapper">
        <div class="column1">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.planerium.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/all-seasons-coloring-page-numbers-one.webp" style="width:50%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Back">
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.planerium.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/all-seasons-coloring-page-numbers-two.webp" style="width:50%;" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Front">
        </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add two of these? Like add the number 3 and when i click on it if shows 3 and 4?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just add as many "mySlides" div as you want for big images and the same work you need to do for small images like adding "column3", "column4" and so on. It will work. Just you need to give a property "overflow-x: scroll" to the ".column-wrapper" div in CSS. Thanks.